# Can't upload Blinky on CH32V003F4P6 using Arduino IDE

Tags: uploading, upload, board

```
Warn : Transport "sdi" was already selected
Ready for Remote Connections
Error: open failed

*** [upload] Error 1
```

I have bought a development board (CH32V003F4P6) and I cannot upload a blinky example to the thing. The Chinese company I got it from doesn't seem to have English support, so I'm struggling to figure out what is wrong. I've got Platform IO, Ardunio, MounRiver, and gcc all installed for CH32V003 and they all have the same problem, they cannot upload to the thing.

I read this [hackaday article](https://hackaday.io/project/191172-using-ch32vxxx-risc-v-and-moun-river/details) and it seems there is both SPI and Serial transfers.

I checked my USB (I'm using Linux) and it shows up.

`Bus 003 Device 048: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter`

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here in order to upload to this thing.

Comment: Do you have rights for accessing serial ports (added correct group, udev rules ...)?

Comment: https://hackaday.com/2023/03/02/a-ch32v003-toolchain-if-you-can-get-one-to-try-it-on/

Comment: google `official WCH Link-E Programmer`

Comment: Yes I have rights to the serial ports. It doesn't work even if I use sudo. The people who sold it to me said I didn't need the WCH Link-E Programmer because this was built in.

Comment: if the programmer is built-in then use the correct software for that programmer

Comment: I have. It is Eclipse, but the error message is the same regardless of the software.